# A problem involving a measurable function

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

Let $f$ be a function defined on a measurable domain $D$.  Suppose $f$ has the property that $\{x:f(x) >q\}$ is a measurable set for each rational number $q$.  Prove that $f$ is a measurable function.

Answer (score 0):

Let $r$ be an integer, there exists a sequence $q_n$, $q_n$ rational such that $lim_nq_n=r, q_n>r$, $(r,+\infty)=\bigcup_n(q_n,+\infty)$ this implies that $f^{-1}(r,+\infty)=\bigcup_nf^{-1}((q_n,+\infty))$ is measurable. Since the $\sigma$-algebra of the Borelian is generated by $(r,+\infty), r\in R$. We deduce that $f$ is measurable.